# Select a field called "return" in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm having a problem with a query in postgres, the table cgporders_items has a field called return, I cannot get actual result of that field with this query, it returns me al ceros.

```
SELECT "Cgporder".id AS "Cgporder__id"
    ,"Sale".preorder_number AS "Sale__preorder_number"
    ,"Contact".id AS "Contact__id"
    ,"Contact".NAME AS "Contact__name"
    ,"Ptype".NAME AS "Ptype__name"
    ,(
        SELECT code
        FROM products
        WHERE id = "CgporderItem".parent_id
        ) AS "Product__parent_code"
    ,"Product".id AS "Product__id"
    ,"Product".code AS "Product__code"
    ,"Product".NAME AS "Product__name"
    ,"CgporderItem".quantity AS "CgporderItem__quantity"
    ,"CgporderItem".return AS "CgporderItem__return"
    ,"CgporderItem".cep_id AS "CgporderItem__cep"
FROM cgporders AS "Cgporder"
INNER JOIN contacts AS "Contact" ON ("Contact".id = "Cgporder".contact_id)
INNER JOIN cgporders_items AS "CgporderItem" ON ("Cgporder".id = "CgporderItem".cgporder_id)
INNER JOIN products AS "Product" ON ("Product".id = "CgporderItem".product_id)
INNER JOIN ptypes AS "Ptype" ON ("Ptype".id = "Product".ptype_id)
LEFT JOIN cgporders_sales AS "CgporderSale" ON ("Cgporder".id = "CgporderSale".cgporder_id)
LEFT JOIN sales AS "Sale" ON ("Sale".id = "CgporderSale".sale_id)
WHERE "CgporderItem".parent_id != 0
    AND "Cgporder"."issue_date" >= '2015-11-27'
    AND "Cgporder"."issue_date" <= '2015-11-27'
    AND "Cgporder"."status" = 'confirmed'
ORDER BY "Ptype".NAME
    ,"Product"."code";
```

There are actually a lots of rows that matches the select condition, but it return cero on "CgporderItem".return AS "CgporderItem__return"

If I make a simple query like select "return" from cgporders_items it works. But in this query it does not work.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried `"CgporderItem"."return" AS "CgporderItem__return"` ? Return is a reserved word, it must be quoted.

Comment: Yes I have tried but it does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"return" is a reserved word in SQL, but not in Postgres. See the list [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html). The following code works find in Postgres (SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d1331)):

```
create table dum  (return int);

select dum.return from dum;
```

Your problem is something else. If I had to guess, the `where` clause is too restrictive (the condition on dates is a bit suspect).